# (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (shares) on node type (Photo)

Tags: facebook

I am trying to access the number of shares on the facebook post. It is giving me this error.

(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (shares) on node type (Photo).

> url - 1600233736676254?fields=shares

Even If I tried **sharedpost** as query parameter, then also I am not able to get the count.

> 1600233736676254?fields=sharedposts

Comment: Code sample? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hit this url - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=1600233736676254%3Ffields%3Dsharedposts&version=v2.10

Comment: A standard post and a photo are different things. The Photo object does not have a `shares` field. `sharedposts` exists, but of course returns only posts visible to your app. You can request the `page_story_id` field to find the post that belongs to the photo. If you query shares for that, you get the same number it shows under the photo post on Facebook (currently 88) - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=436549486378024_1600233736676254%3Ffields%3Dshares&version=v2.10